# Converting a UTC ISO 8601 string to milliseconds gives a time of +12 hours

Tags: java, android, datetime, utc, iso8601

I am receiving a time from my server in `UTC ISO8601` format like so:

```
2018-01-25T05:14:03.4973436
```

I am converting this `string` to `milliseconds` and I am `generating` a time elapsed value using my current `time` like so:

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpan(String timeStamp) {

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

    Date date = format.parse(timeStamp);

    long past = date.getTime();

    int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() + offset;

    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            past,
            now,
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

However, for some reason, the code produces an immediate difference of `12 hours` between ***past*** and ***now***. I'm not sure why there is such a difference but for instance this `UTC` string `( 2018-01-25T05:14:03.4973436 )` generates the following `milliseconds` value `( 1516857243000 )` which doesn't really correspond to the current `time` in `milliseconds`.

The interesting part of all of this is that there's this automatic `12 hour` difference. I made sure that I use `"HH"` instead of `"hh"` to account for `AM/PM` differences so I don't know what's causing this discrepancy.

**UPDATED USING JAVA8 time - still the same behavior**

I have updated the code with the following snippet and I am getting the exact same behavior ( 12 hour immediate difference )

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpan(String timeStamp) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSS");
    LocalDateTime fromCustomPattern = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            fromCustomPattern.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
            Instant.now().toEpochMilli(),
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: java.time classes parse ISO 8601 without any explicit formatter, so `OffsetDateTime past = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);` and then `long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(past, OffsetDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC));` (just produced 59219).

Comment: @OleV.V., this only works for API 26+ . I did try ThreeTenABP but I am still getting the same result. Please, see my updated description.

Comment: 12 hours sounds like pretty much. Which time zone are you in? It comes from your JVM’s time zone setting.

Comment: I take `DateUtils` to be [`android.text.format.DateUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html), is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Two issues:

1. `long` millisecond times coming from `Date` and `System.currentTimeInMillis()` are in UTC. Adding timezone offsets is not necessary when comparing such values. You should not be adjusting for timezone like that.
2. `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` etc. only support milliseconds resolution but your source strings have 100 nanosecond resolution. There are implementations that would take the `4973436` in `2018-01-25T05:14:03.4973436` as milliseconds, resulting in 436 millis and overflowing the 4973000 to other fields. This happens on some older API levels, newer ones truncate/pad the millis part to exactly 3 digits.

   To fix that, you can truncate your inputs to 3 fractional digits yourself, or use newer `java.time` APIs (API 26+, backport available for example in ThreeTenABP library).

Comment: I have updated my code to use the java.time libraray using the ThreeTenABP library but I am still getting the exact same results. Please see my updated description.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it can be made to work with java.time, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310:

```
public static CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpan(String timeStamp) {
    LocalDateTime fromIso8601 = LocalDateTime.parse(timeStamp);
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
            fromIso8601.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant().toEpochMilli(),
            Instant.now().toEpochMilli(),
            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

You don’t need an explicit formatter. The modern date and time classes parse ISO 8601 as their default. Since your date-time string is in UTC, convert it using `atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` (not your default time zone, this must have been what gave you the wrong result).

To use the above code with ThreeTenABP, make sure you import from `org.threeten.bp`:

```
import org.threeten.bp.Instant;
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDateTime;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneOffset;
```

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time`to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.